# problem with a method undefined for a special type

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I'd like to implement a program of klondike game but I've got a problem with a method that adds a card on the top of a deck (that method takes a card object as a parameter). It is defined in a mother class(the mother class has a constructor that creates an ArrayList of cards' objects). I call in a subclass's method that sets back the cards on the stack. Yet, there's an exception, when I call it on the instance of the subclass, It says that "The method add_card_on_top(Card) is undefined for the type ArrayList" and I'd like to know what is accurately the issue.

Here is the code of the main class;

```
public abstract class Deck 
{
protected ArrayList<Card>deck=new ArrayList<>();
public Deck()
{
    this.deck=new ArrayList<Card>();
}
public Card get_card_on_top()
{
    return deck.get(0);
}
public Card get_cards(int i)
{
    return this.deck.get(i);
}
public void add_card_on_top(Card card)
{
    deck.add(0, card);
}
```

Here is the code of the subclass;

```
package patience;
public class Stack extends Deck 
{
public Stack(Deck_dealer deck_dealer) 
    {
    this.deck=deck_dealer.deck;
    }
public void get_card_on_stack_put_on_discard(Discard discard, int i)
    {
    discard.add_card_on_top(this.deck.get(i));
    this.deck.remove(i);
    }
public void set_back_cards_on_stack(Discard discard)
    {
    if (this.deck.isEmpty())
        {
        for(int i=0; i<discard.size(); i++)
            {
            this.deck.add_card_on_top(discard.deck.get(i));
            discard.deck.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to call `add_card_on_top` on `this.deck` which is an `ArrayList`. But that method doesn't exist in `ArrayList`. You probably just want to call `this.add_card_on_top` instead of `this.deck.add_card_on_top`.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the Java style guide and following the conventions of the language. This isn't going to solve your problem, but it does make it much easier for other people to read and understand your code quickly.